# can't add header info properly using jstoXML

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to convert my table into xml. currently, I have two rows.  But I can not add the header information properly using jsToXml.Here is my code.

```
import { toXML } from 'jstoxml';

export class NgbdModalComponentModule {
      constructor() {
        const table = [
          {
            row: 'bar'
          },
          {
            row: 'bar2'
          }
        ];
        const xmlOptions = {
          header: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>',
          indent: ' '
        };
    
        console.log(toXML(table, xmlOptions));
      }
    }
```

and output is look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<row>bar</row>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<row>bar2</row>
```

But Output should be like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<row>bar</row>
<row>bar2</row>
```

I have also created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nf8k31-uyjdob?file=app/modal-component.module.ts).

Comment: That’s quite a strange setup you have there.. why no app module and an app root? Also, doing stuff like this inside a component (and then also inside the constructor) is asking for trouble. It should really be done in a proper service. Advice: start with a new angular project, do not touch main.ts. What you have now is not a good foundation.

Comment: I think it adds the header to every `root-node`, in this case `foo` & `foo`. If you try to nest it, it works..

Comment: @mikeone i did not copy all the app modules. please check the stackbliz if you need them. I just copied the main part of my code. that's it

Comment: It looks off :-) - anyway, your issue is that xml only allows a single root element. All other elements must be children of the root element. That’s probably the reason it creates 2 ‘documents’ for you.. So the output you wish is simply not valid XML..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the heads up and the clear description.  This isn't due to your code, it's due to a bug in `jstoxml`.  It's now fixed in `2.1.1`!

Issue for reference: https://github.com/davidcalhoun/jstoxml/issues/48